# How to annotate list of proteins with KEGG orthology groups?

Tags: uniprot, kegg, orthologues

I've got a list of proteins, complete with Uniprot IDs (for some of them) and gene names. I'd like to group them into orthology groups based on data from KEGG, but I have no idea how to add a column with KEGG groups. I've tried poking around in the documentation for UniProt, but all I can find is this page on KEGG - no mention of how to link to KEGG data. I've also found these KEGG mapper tools ([web portal](https://www.kegg.jp/kegg/tool/conv_id.html) and [command line](https://www.genome.jp/kegg/mapper/)) but those don't seem to be what I need in order to cluster my proteins into groups of KEGG orthologues.

I've tried using R via the following:

```
library(KEGGREST)

kegg_ids <- KEGGREST::keggConv(
  target = "genes",
  source = paste("uniprot", uniprot_ids, sep = ':'))
```

But this turns up matches for only a fraction of my protein IDs... and anyway, only about half of them have those IDs - the rest are human proteins for which I only have the gene name.